# Returned node was not a DOM element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to access a dynamic ID with Selenium on java. Because the ID changes each time I'm trying to access the textarea through its class id like this

```
sign = driver.findElement(By.className("aoT"));
    sign.sendKeys(subject);
```

when I run this I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Returned node was not a DOM element
```

and I can't seem to find much information on what a DOM element is in this context or as to what I should do to fix the problem.

I'm pulling the Class name from

```
<input name="subjectbox" id=":144" class="aoT" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true" tabindex="1" placeholder="Subject">
```

I can't take the id because that changes everytime the page is loaded

Comment: you need to provide more info. are you sure `aoT` is an existing class? Try printing out what `sign` is

Comment: Please give HTML code

Comment: Sorry, I've edited it so it now contains the HTML I'm drawing from